# apk size is increased due to armeabi file having .so files.How to decrease it?

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, metadata

I have developed an application using JNI. When I am using JNI Native libraries it will automatically generate .so files, because of these files my application size will increase.

Could anyone suggest how to decrease the size of these .so files ?

Comment: You can't decrease size of .so files as far as I know. But maybe you can use Proguard for code minification.

Comment: Means, you want me to keep all .so jar files in Proguard file or esle any other Proguard modification.